implementation of the user and friends list entity relationship in conceptual DB schema
I'm trying to create an option for a user to have a friends list, i.e. to have a relationship with other users. But I'm struggling with the implementation of the relationship between these two entities. I understand that there should be a 1:1 relationship between the user and the friends list, since the user can only have one list, but I have no idea how to make a reverse relationship.

